# What is void* and to what variables/objects it can point to

Tags: c++, c, ios

Specifically, can it point to int/float etc.?
What about objects like NSString and the like?
Any examples will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`void*` is such a pointer, that any pointer can be implicitly converted to `void*`.

For example;

```
int* p = new int;
void* pv = p; //OK;
p = pv; //Error, the opposite conversion must be explicit in C++ (in C this is OK too)
```

Also note that pointers to const cannot be converted to `void*` without a `const_cast`

E.g.

```
const int * pc = new const int(4);
void * pv = pc; //Error
const void* pcv = pc; //OK
```

Hth.

Answer (score 18):

In C any pointer can point to any address in memory, as the type information is in the pointer, not in the target. So an int* is just a pointer to some memory location, which is believed to be an integer. A void* pointer, is just a pointer to a memory location where the type is not defined (could be anything).

Thus any pointer can be cast to void*, but not the other way around, because casting (for example) a void pointer to an int pointer is *adding* information to it - by performing the cast, you are declaring that the target data is integer, so naturally you have to explicitly say this. The other way around, all you are doing is saying that the int pointer is some kind of pointer, which is fine.

It's probably the same in C++.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, in C, unlike C++ the conversion from void* to int* is implicit too...

Comment: @Armen Hmm, seems you're right - I should probably have checked that.

Comment: Does `void *` = `id` in Objective-C?

Comment: @randy marsh, no, but` void*` is similar to `id` in Objective-C http://dobegin.com/objc-id-type/ `id` is a pointer to a struct that gets treated specially by the compiler.

Answer (score 5):

A `void *` can point at any data-like thing in memory, like an integer value, a struct, or whatever.

Do note, however, that you cannot freely convert between `void *` and function pointers. This is because on some architectures, code is not in the same address space as data, and thus it's possible that address 0x00000000 for code refers to a different set of bits than address 0x00000000 for data does.

It would be possible to implement the compiler so that `void *` is large enough to remember the difference, but in general I think this is not done, instead the language leaves it undefined.

On typical/mainstream computers, code and data reside in the same address space, and then the compilers typically generate sensible results if you do store a function pointer into a `void *`, since it can be quite useful.

Answer (score 5):

Besides everything else that was already said by the other users, a `void*` it's commonly used in callback definitions. This allows your callback to receive *user data* of any type, including your own defined objects/structs, which should be casted to the appropriate type before using it:

```
void my_player_cb(int reason, void* data)
{
    Player_t* player = (Player_t*)data;

    if (reason == END_OF_FILE)
    {    
        if (player->playing)
        {
          // execute stop(), release allocated resources and 
          // start() playing the next file on the list
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`void*` can point to an address *in memory* but the syntax has no type-information. you can cast it to any pointer-type you want but it is your responsibility that that type matches the semantics of the data.

Comment: Not exactly. In C++, you can't convert a const X* to void* without a const_cast

Comment: Also, last I looked, in bare C/C++ memory contents included no runtime type information unless explicitly included in the data itself (through for example a magic constant, which a framework might very well use).

Comment: @Michael: If you have a non-void pointer then _the syntax_ carriers the type-information. @Armen: The reason why c++ (and c!) compilers dont cast const-pointers to void-pointers is that const-pointers are not pointers to memory addresses but instead are mapped to globals at *link*-time.

Comment: That MAY be true if we speak about compile-time (link-time) constants. In C++, a constant object's value need not necessarily be known link-time.

Comment: "void star"? How about void pointer? That's its name after all.