# void pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is void* and to what variables/objects it can point to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104640/what-is-void-and-to-what-variables-objects-it-can-point-to)

What does `void*` represent in C?
Please give a reason for the use, too...

Answer (score 5):

`void *` is a "typeless" pointer in C, that is, a pointer that may point to an object of any type. It is used if one does not know the type of the data to be stored beforehand.

Comment: +1 ... but you cannot store data through a `void *`: you have to know the type of data beforehand. If you don't know the type of data you're working with, you're in a very bad situation :)

Comment: @pmg: You are right, of course. The beforehand means that you do no know the type when designing a data structure. When you use the data structure, you should know what data you want to store.