# How can I create an array of void whose size will be specified by the user input from command line?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2013, command-line

I want to ask user enter an integer to create a 2D array like this:

`void* myArray_1[2][userInput];`

which is not allowed by compiler because the `userInput` is not constant.

Then I tried this:

```
void** myArray_2 = new void*[rowCount];
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    myArray_2[i] = new void[colCount];
```

which causes the below error:

> Error: array of void is NOT allowed.

How can I create an array of void whose size will be specified by the user input from command line?

*Edit:*
my function prototype is:
`errorType EventGet ( EVENT_HANDLE hEvent, void * pBuffer);`

I used this:

```
void* myArray_3[2][10];
...
myArray_3[0][count++] = myOtherArray[0]; //myOtherArray[0] contains a handle and myOtherArray is an 1D array with size of 2.
EventGet ( myEventHandle, myArray_3[0][i]);
```

and I got correct result. Now the only thing I want is to allow the user to specify the second dimension size instead of 10.

Comment: What do you expect to put in an array of void? The error message is pretty clear that this kind of thing isn't allowed. The dynamic size doesn't even matter.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<void*>> myVector(2, std::vector<void*>(userInput));`

Comment: Perhaps you want a 2D array of `void*` instead: `void*** myArray ...`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I want to pass it to a function which accepts a 2D array of void. Yes, I want a 2D array of `void*`.

Comment: "a function which accepts a 2D array of void" Please show the signature of the function. I doubt you understand it correctly since an array of void is not allowed. Are you sure it isn't a 2d array of `void*`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice don't be confused. [A dynamic 2D array is basically an array of pointers to arrays.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/936702/4439444)

Comment: @GmtK: You are the one who is confused.  No function can accept a 2D array of void.  (At least, not in C++).  Show us the *actual* signature of the function.

Comment: @GmtK Yes, you can have an array of `void*`. This is not the same as a 2D array of void however, since you cannot allocate an array of void to each `void*`.

Comment: @ I am poor in English. Sorry for it. I meant I pass that 2D array of void to my function. My function has the `void *` type argument. I will edit my question soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is void\* and to what variables/objects it can point to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104640/what-is-void-and-to-what-variables-objects-it-can-point-to)

Comment: `void*` is NOT a 2D array. It is a pointer to...something...which may be the first element of an array or a single value. Note that if it points to an array, the array must hold elements of some legal type, such as `int`.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626786/what-does-void-mean-and-how-to-use-it) is probably a better link than the previous one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kill point is not the passing, the pointing, or any of its ilk, the problem is here:

```
myArray_2[i] = new void[colCount];
```

`new void[colCount];` says "Make me an array of `void`." `void` is a placeholder for "no type" and cannot be instantiated. You effectively would be creating an array of nothing. Nothing has no definition. No size. This cannot be done.

However, OP wishes to duplicate the [Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

```
void* myArray_1[2][userInput];
```

To do this, OP needs to indirect one level further, and store a 2 dimensional array (an array of arrays, really) of `void *`.

```
void*** myArray_2 = new void**[rowCount];
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    myArray_2[i] = new void*[colCount];
```

This will give the appearance of `void* myArray_1[2][userInput];`

The preferred C++ approach is to use a container to manage the memory for you and [use a `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<std::vector<void*>> myVector_1(2, std::vector<void*>(userInput));
```

Defines a `vector` that contains a `vector` that contains pointers to `void`. The outer `vector` is presized to 2 elements and the inner vector is presized to `userInput` elements.

Comment: Golden sentence: _OP needs to indirect one level further._ It works! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you need an array of `void*`. This is not the same as a 2D array of `void` since you cannot allocate an array of `void` as the error states. The first level is correct:

```
void** myArray_2 = new void*[rowCount];
```

However, the second level must be allocated with a valid type such as

```
void** myArray_2 = new void*[rowCount];
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    myArray_2[i] = new int[colCount];
```

Of course, you can put whatever type you wish other than `int`. You can also mix types if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Based off what Igor Tandetnik has commented, and given that you know the outer size is constant 2, you could do something like:

```
std::vector<void*> myArray[2] = {
  std::vector<void*>(userInput), std::vector<void*>(userInput)
};

for (int i = 0; i < userInput; ++i) {
  work on myArray[0][i]...
  work on myArray[1][i]...
}
```